# Sending mail with EWS and OAuth 403 error

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

A while ago I wrote in C# a simple utility method that was called by an application to send emails automatically.

The application used to authenticate in EWS with Basic authentication (username + password) and everything worked fine.

Starting from September 2022 Microsoft started disabling this now deprecated authentication method, so I decided to update this utility method with an OAuth system autentication.
The method is the following:

```
   public static void SendMail(string to, string cc, string bcc, string replyTo, string from, string subject, bool isHtmlFormat, string body, string[] attachments)
    {
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("my-app-id")//app id
                                                      .WithClientSecret("my-client-secret") //Client secret
                                                      .WithTenantId("my-tenant-id") //Id tenant
                                                      .Build();

        var authResult = cca.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync().Result;

        string[] recipients = to.Replace(" ", "").Split(';');
        string[] repliesTo  = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(replyTo) ? Array.Empty<string>() : replyTo.Replace(" ", "").Split(';');
        string[] ccs        = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cc)      ? Array.Empty<string>() : cc.Replace(" ", "").Split(';');
        string[] bccs       = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bcc)     ? Array.Empty<string>() : bcc.Replace(" ", "").Split(';');

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService
        {
            Url                = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
            Credentials        = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
            ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, from)
        };

        service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", from); //Include x-anchormailbox header

        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(service)
        {
            From = new EmailAddress(from),
            Subject = subject, 
            Body = new MessageBody(isHtmlFormat ? BodyType.HTML : BodyType.Text, body)
            
        };

        emailMessage.ToRecipients.AddRange(recipients);
        emailMessage.ReplyTo.AddRange(repliesTo);
        emailMessage.CcRecipients.AddRange(ccs);
        emailMessage.BccRecipients.AddRange(bccs);

        foreach (string attachment in attachments ?? Array.Empty<string>())
        {
            emailMessage.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attachment);
        }

        emailMessage.Send();
    }
```

The function is called in a very straightforward way:

```
MailHelper.SendMail("MyEmail@myCompany.com", null, null, null, "NoReply@myCompany.com", "Test subject", false, "This is a test body", null);
```

The problem is that as soon as the Method  emailMessage.Send(); is called, a Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException reporting a 403 forbidden error is thrown.

I already registered the app in the Azure Active Directory interface, set a secret and set the following permissions:
[image]

The accounts in my tenant are set to allow Exchange services:
[image: permissions]

I already double checked IDs and account names to be sure it was not a trivial mistake, but I'm not an expert when it comes to EWS, so I'm surely missing something, unfortunately I don't know where.

Thanks id advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error **`403 Forbidden`** usually occurs if you don't have required permissions or missed granting **admin consent** to the added API permissions.

Please **note** that, the code you mentioned is using **"Client credentials flow"** that works with only **Application** permissions but you added all **Delegated** permissions.

In that case, you will get **`403 Forbidden`** error even you granted consent to **Delegated** permissions.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and added API permissions same as you like below:

[image]

Now, I generated an access token using **"Client credentials flow"** via ***Postman*** like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appID
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:secret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to **send mail** with below query, I got **`403 Forbidden`** error like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/sendmail
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add ***Application permissions*** and grant ***admin consent*** to them like below:

[image]

Now I generated the **access token** again and used it in running below query to send sample mail:

[image]

In your case, add **Application** permissions by granting **admin consent** to them and run the code again.