# OAuth2 authenticated e-mails from PowerShell to Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, email, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, exchange-online

OAuth2 for the 100th time, sorry, but I'm on the verge of despair here. I need to send authenticated e-mails from a PowerShell script to my own Exchange Online Mailbox (I'm also the tenant admin, if this matters). So I registered an App in AzureAD.

Display name: `MyApp`
Supported account types: `My organization only` 
App permissions:
Microsoft Graph\User.Read (Delegated, Granted for MyDomain)
Office 365 Exchange Online\IMAP.AccessAsApp (Application, Granted for MyDomain)

Probably the `Microsoft Graph` API isn't needed here. The app has a secret with an expiration period of 730 days.

I created a new Exchange Service Principal and granted FullAccess to my mailbox:

```
$app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString MyApp
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -DisplayName "MyServicePrincipalName"
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $azureUserName -User $app.ObjectId -AccessRights FullAccess
```

Here's the result of `Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $azureUserName | fl`:

```
IsOwner         : False
AccessRights    : {FullAccess, ReadPermission}
Deny            : False
InheritanceType : All
User            : NT AUTHORITY\SELF
UserSid         : S-X-Y-Z
Identity        : admin
IsInherited     : False
IsValid         : True
ObjectState     : Unchanged

IsOwner         : False
AccessRights    : {FullAccess}
Deny            : False
InheritanceType : All
User            : MyServicePrincipalName
UserSid         : S-X-Y-Z-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
Identity        : admin
IsInherited     : False
IsValid         : True
ObjectState     : Unchanged
```

With this configured, I tried to add an e-mail to my inbox. Here's the script I used:

```
Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

$tenantID = "asdf1234"
$appID = "asdf1234"
$secretValue = "asdf1234"
$userName = "myazureuser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
$senderAddress = $userName
$recipientAddress = $userName

$scope = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
$tokenURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Define the OAuth 2.0 token request body
$tokenRequestBody = @{
    client_id     = $appID
    scope         = $scope
    client_secret = $secretValue
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
} 

# Request an access token
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenURL -Method POST -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $tokenRequestBody

# Access the access token
$accessToken = $response.access_token

# Connect to Office 365 IMAP service
$server = "outlook.office365.com"
$port = 993

$tcpClient = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($server, $port)
$sslStream = [System.Net.Security.SslStream]::new($tcpClient.GetStream())
$sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($server, $null, [System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols]::Tls12, $false)
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($sslStream)
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($sslStream)

# Read server response
$reader.ReadLine()

# Compose the email
$emailSubject = "Test e-mail"
$emailBody = "This is a test e-mail"
$email = "To: $recipientAddress`nFrom: $senderAddress`nSubject: $emailSubject`n`n$emailBody"

# build XOAUTH2 login string with accesstoken and username
$accessString ="user=" + $userName + "$([char]0x01)auth=Bearer " + $accessToken + "$([char]0x01)$([char]0x01)"
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($accessString)
$loginString = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)

# Authenticate using XOAUTH2
$command = "A01 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 $loginString"
$writer.WriteLine($command)

# Capture the response
$ResponseStr = $reader.ReadLine()

# Check if the response indicates success
if ($ResponseStr -like "*OK AUTHENTICATE completed.") {
    Write-Host "Authentication successful."
} else {
    Write-Host "Authentication failed: $ResponseStr"
}

# Send an email
$command = "A01 APPEND INBOX (\Seen) $(" + $email.Length + ")"
$writer.WriteLine($command)
$writer.WriteLine($email)
$writer.WriteLine()

# Logout and clean up sessions
$writer.WriteLine("A01 Logout")
$writer.Close()
$reader.Close()
$sslStream.Close()
$tcpClient.Close()
```

I get an access token, the `$response` looks like this:

| token_type | expires_in | ext_expires_in | access_token |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bearer | 3599 | 3599 | myaccesstokenstring |

But after I execute `$writer.WriteLine($command)`, it hangs and after a few seconds I get the error:

```
Authentication failed: * BYE Connection is closed. 13
```

I don't really understand, what I did wrong. Maybe it's completely stupid for those who know what they are doing. I'm just trying to send e-mail notifications to myself and my understanding of the whole concept here is very basic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try lowercasing `"myAzureUser@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"`

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen: The real username is all lower case, i just corrected it in the example.

Comment: Of you add the Graph permission mail.send you can send mails using the Graph API (which is much easier to do). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http for the documentation on this

Comment: When I tried your code, I too got [same error](https://i.imgur.com/Y27ByoF.png). Alternatively, you can send mail using Microsoft Graph API by granting `Mail.Send` permission of **Application** type. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74125340/sending-mail-with-ews-and-oauth-403-error/74126725#74126725)

Comment: @Sridevi and bluuf, thanks a lot for the hint, this works perfectly and with one third of the code. I just don't understand this concept, why should we use the Exchange Online API if it just works with the Graph API? I guess the Graph\Mail Permissions are more global than the EO persmissions, but limited? Or is Graph replacing the EO API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatively, you can make use of **Microsoft Graph API** to send an
> authenticated email from PowerShell.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **`Mail.Send`** Application permission as below:

[image]

Now, I ran below modified script to **send mail** by installing `Microsoft.Graph` module like this:

```
#Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
#Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions

$tenantID = "tenantID"
$appID = "appID"
$secretValue = "secret"
$ClientSecretPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secretValue -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appID, $ClientSecretPass

# Connect to Microsoft Graph with Client Secret
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential

$userName = "sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$senderAddress = $userName
$recipientAddress = $userName

$emailSubject = "Test e-mail"
$emailBody = "This is a test e-mail"
$type = "Text" 

$params = @{
    Message         = @{
        Subject       = $emailSubject
        Body          = @{
            ContentType = $type
            Content     = $emailBody
        }
        ToRecipients  = @(
            @{
                EmailAddress = @{
                    Address = $recipientAddress
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

Send-MgUserMail -UserId $senderAddress -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in **`Inbox`** folder of user, mail added successfully as below:

[image]

Note that, The Graph API is **not** replacing the Exchange Online API. But you can access multiple Microsoft 365 services including Exchange Online, SharePoint, OneDrive, Teams, etc. via Graph API.

As Microsoft is moving towards consolidating its APIs under the **Microsoft Graph API**, it's possible that the Exchange Online API may eventually be deprecated in favor of the Graph API. So, it is recommended to use the Graph API for new development that simplifies the complexity.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Just a side note. When I modified my code yesterday to use the Graph API, I struggled with the module import, because `Import-Module Microsoft.Graph` is just too big. Maybe it would help someone else who reads this, if you add the line `Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions` to the code in your answer.