# Sending email OAuth2 Office365

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have an application's clientId, tenantId, and secret from registering an app in Microsoft Azure services.

I managed to get a token, from here: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D)
I also figured out that the scope should be this: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

I tried to send an email with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail endPoint, but I finally realized he /me is not good for me (I tried to replace the "me" with the email address that I want to send the email from, but that also not working).

Please give me help how should I use this API? I just want to send an email with OAuth2.

Comment: `POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Now it says "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.". Is it an Azure configuration error, meaning somehow need to connect the appliaction and the email that I want to send from? Or Somehow I need to login with that email address (I only get the token from the clientId, tenantId etc. So the email adress password was not provided)?

Comment: try to check the token your getting in jwt.io and look at roles/scopes that are included in the token.

Comment: [this answer](the email address that I want to send the email from) might help you I had test code and explanation inside it, and pls pay attention to the comment, I'm afraid `the email address that I want to send the email from` wasn't assigned a correct license.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70780395/14574199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD application and granted `Mail.Send` permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check whether it has **roles** claim with **`Mail.Send`** permission:

[image]

When I used this token to send mail with below API call via Postman, I got **response** like this:

```json
 POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId/sendMail
 {
  "message": {
    "subject": "Invitation for Diwali Event",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "Hi Sri! We welcome you to attend Diwali event on 2 November 2023"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in user's **`Sent Items`** where mail sent successfully as below:

[image]

In your case, *"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again"* error occurs if you granted `Mail.Send` permission of **Delegated** type for client credentials flow.

To **resolve** the error, make sure to grant `Mail.Send` permission of **Application** type. Refer this [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74125340/sending-mail-with-ews-and-oauth-403-error/74126725#74126725) that I previously answered.